# Kotlin - Can you specify return type explicitly on a lambda?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, rx-java, anonymous-function

I have an interface

```
private interface WithTokenExecutor<T> {
    fun execute(token: Token): Single<T>
}
```

and a function withToken that asynchronously gets an access token then returns the executed `WithTokenExecutor` parameter with the new token.

```
private fun <T> withToken(executor: WithTokenExecutor<T>): Single<T> { 
    return essentialApiTokenProvider.getTokenObservable(true) // returns an observable with the token
        .flatMap { token -> executor.execute(token)) }
}
```

Then I to call the function with the:

```
fun getAppData(apps: List<String>): Single<AppsList> {
    return withToken(object : WithTokenExecutor<AppsList> {
        override fun execute(token: Token): Single<AppsList> {
            return api.getDetails(token) // retuns a Single<AppsList>
        }
    })
}
```

This works, so my question is is it possible to change the return statement from an anonymous class to lambda even if the return type of the withToken and the WithTokenExecutor functions are generic?

I have tried doing this:

```
return withToken({ token -> api.getDetails(token) })
```

but the compiler says:

`Type inference failed: fun <T> withToken(executor: StoreManager.WithTokenExecutor<T>):Single<T> cannot be applied to ((???) -> Single<AppsList>)`

Is there a way to explicitly define the return type of these functions while still keeping the lambda?

Comment: Your `withToken` function does not accept lambdas as argument. You have to explicitly create an overload that does so. Functional interfaces that will allow you to input lambda instead of interface object are still in planning phase for Kotlin 1.4: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond/

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of modifying your declaration of `WithTokenExecutor` to:

```
typealias WithTokenExecutor<T> = (t : Token) -> Single<T>
```

...you will be able to implement your `getAppData` like this:

```
fun getAppData(apps: List<String>): Single<AppsList> = withToken { api.getDetails(it) }
```

If changing the declaration is not possible, it seems like you are out of luck until Kotlin 1.4 as @Pawel points mentions in the comments.